# How to create the following shape in css with clip-path or any other way

Tags: css, clip-path

I am trying to achieve this shape but not being able to get the desired result. I am using it in a bootstrap carousel

[image: Preview]

Below is  what I've got so far

```css
div {
  height:300px;
  width:350px;
  background: #414141;
   clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 23%, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
 filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px 4px #2ec);
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My attempt

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 600px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  margin: 10px 0 0 15px;  
  border: 2px gold solid;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transform: rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-2deg);
}


figure::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -8px;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transform: rotateY(5deg) rotateZ(4deg) scale(.95);
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3pb.jpg" alt="a cute cat" />
</figure>
```

---

Final result

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your solution and you've saved me. but is it possible to implement  this in a carousel where the dropshadow can be maybe the next or previous image. thanks

Comment: @amn because in the code of the OP the units were defined in pixel

Comment: Getting the concept was what i needed the most, so will try and convert them to em or percentage.